# Reducing assignment of temporary object to in-place construction

Tags: c++, optimization, assignment-operator, placement-new

Using `std::list` supporting move semantics as an example.

```
std::list<std::string> X;
... //X is used in various ways
X=std::list<std::string>({"foo","bar","dead","beef"});
```

The most straightforward way for compiler to do the assignment since C++11 is:

1. destroy `X`
2. construct `std::list`
3. move `std::list` to `X`

Now, compiler isn't allowed to do following instead:

1. destroy X
2. contruct `std::list` in-place

because while this obviously saves another `memcpy` it eliminates assignment. What is the convenient way of making second behaviour possible and usable? Is it planned in future versions of C++?

My guess is that C++ still does not offer that except with writing:

```
X.~X();
new(&X) std::list<std::string>({"foo","bar","dead","beef"});
```

Am I right?

Comment: For those of use that don't know what QList does, why not use std::list as your example.

Comment: @latedeveloper: Because `QList` is an array of pointers, while `std::list` is a linked list. Those are very different types, with different allocation properties.

Comment: @NicolBolas: `QList` is used purely demostratively, it's properties do not matter much. Their point is valid.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow: But your question is about efficiency of assignment. So its allocation and move costs very much do matter.

Comment: @NicolBolas they both support move semantics so in best case of implementations of both assignment of both of them is cheap. Am I right? Either way it is more efficient to construct in place than move.

Comment: Your ideas about what's permitted or not, are wrong. The compiler is permitted to substitute any optimization as long as it preserves the observable effects. This is called the "as if" rule. Possible optimizations include removing all of that code, if it does not affect anything observable. In particular, your "isn't allowed" for the second example is completely false, and the reasoning "it eliminates assignment" applies also to your first example, where you draw the opposite conclusion, i.e. there's a self-contradiction right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do it by defining operator= to take an initializer list.
For std::list, just call

```
    X = {"foo","bar","dead","beef"}.
```

In your case, what was happening is actually:

1. Construct a temporary
2. Call move assignment operator on X with the temporary

On most objects, such as std::list, this won't actually be expensive compared to simply constructing an object.

However, it still incurs additional allocations for the internal storage of the second std::list, which could be avoided: we could reuse the internal storage already allocated for X if possible. What is happenning is:

1. Construct: the temporary allocates some space for the elements
2. Move: the pointer is moved to X; the space used by X before is freed

Some objects overload the assignment operator to take an initializer list, and it is the case for [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/) and [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/operator=/). Such an operator may use the storage already allocated internally, which is the most effective solution here.

// Please insert the usual rambling about premature optimization here

Comment: I replaced `QList` with `std::list` because it did not really matter to me.

Comment: Thanks; initializer list assignment operator works with std::list; I'm going to edit

Comment: "Please insert the usual rambling about premature optimization here" - C++ is a performance-oriented language, it is always interesting to see how it minimizes overheads.

Comment: Agreed. Dynamic memory allocation is often a big overhead. Reusing preallocated space with move is important, but it will be negligible compared to, say, using std::list instead of std::vector. Please be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it planned in future versions of C++?

No. And thank goodness for that.

Assignment is *not* the same as destroy-then-create. `X` is not destroyed in your assignment example. `X` is a live object; the *contents* of `X` may be destroyed, but `X` itself never is. And *nor should it be*.

If you want to destroy `X`, then you have that ability, using the explicit-destructor-and-placement-new. Though thanks to the possibility of `const` members, you'll also need to launder the pointer to the object if you want to be safe. But assignment should *never* be considered equivalent to that.

If efficiency is your concern, it's much better to use the `assign` member function. By using `assign`, the `X` has the opportunity to reuse the existing allocations. And this would almost certainly make it faster than your "destroy-plus-construct" version. The cost of moving a linked list into another object is trivial; the cost of having to destroy all of those allocations only to allocate them again is not.

This is especially important for `std::list`, as it has a *lot* of allocations.

Worst-case scenario, `assign` will be no less efficient than whatever else you could come up with from outside the class. And best-case, it will be far better.

Comment: I have added a line `and writing a function to construct return object in place without same manual destruction and raw pointers is even more impossible.` to the end of question. Could you clarify that too?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a statement involving a move assignment:

```
x = std::move(y);
```

The destructor is not called for `x` before doing the move. However, after the move, at some point the destructor will be called for `y`. The idea behind a move assignment operator is that it might be able to move the contents of `y` to `x` in a simple way (for example, copying a pointer to `y`'s storage into `x`). It also has to ensure its previous contents are destroyed properly (it may opt to swap this with `y`, because you know `y` may not be used anymore, and that `y`'s destructor will be called).

If the move assignment is inlined, the compiler might be able to deduce that all the operations necessary for moving storage from `y` to `x` are just equivalent to in-place construction.

Comment: So, the move constructor should reimplement some part of destructor?

Comment: I understand that assignment may be inlined but it still won't be an in-place construction right?

Comment: I was talking about the move *assignment* operator, this is different from the move *constructor*. In any case, the move assignment operator can either destruct the LHS itself, or choose to swap with the RHS, because it can count on the destructor being called on the RHS.

Comment: If the assignment is inlined, the compiler might be able to track how values are moved around, and see that it could just as well rewrite it as an in-place construction. However, that is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Re your final question

> **”** Am I right?

No.

Your ideas about what's permitted or not, are wrong. The compiler is permitted to substitute any optimization as long as it preserves the observable effects. This is called the "as if" rule. Possible optimizations include removing all of that code, if it does not affect anything observable. In particular, your "isn't allowed" for the second example is completely false, and the reasoning "it eliminates assignment" applies also to your first example, where you draw the opposite conclusion, i.e. there's a self-contradiction right there.